# How to fix the recursively called rectangles in this fractal?

Tags: java, recursion, graphics, computer-science, fractals

```
// Lab17bvst.java
// The student, starting version of the Lab17b assignment.


import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;


public class Lab17bvst extends Applet
{

public void paint (Graphics g)
{
    drawSquare1(g,1000,650);
    //drawMoreSquares(10, g, 500, 325);
}

public void drawSquare1(Graphics g, int maxX, int maxY)
{
    int midX = maxX/2;
    int midY = maxY/2;
    int startWidth = maxX/4;
    int startHeight = maxY/4;
    int tlX = midX - (startWidth/2);
    int tlY = midY - (startHeight/2);

    g.fillRect(tlX,tlY,startWidth,startHeight);
    drawTL(g, tlX,tlY,startWidth,startHeight,10);
    drawTR(g, tlX,tlY,startWidth,startHeight,10);
    drawBR(g, tlX,tlY,startWidth,startHeight,10);
    drawBL(g, tlX,tlY,startWidth,startHeight,10);
}



private void drawBL(Graphics g, int tlX, int tlY, int startWidth, int startHeight, int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void drawBR(Graphics g, int tlX, int tlY, int startWidth, int startHeight, int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void drawTL(Graphics g, int x, int y, int w, int h, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return;
    }
    g.fillRect( x , y , w , h);

    drawTL( g , x - w / 2 , y - h / 2 , w / 2 , h / 2, n - 1);
}

public void drawTR(Graphics g, int x, int y, int w, int h, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return;
    }
    g.fillRect( x , y , w , h);
    drawTR( g , x + 2 * w - (w/2) , y - h / 2 , w / 2 , h / 2, n - 1);
}



public void delay(long n)
{
    n *= 1000;
    long startDelay = System.nanoTime();
    long endDelay = 0;
    while (endDelay - startDelay < n)
        endDelay = System.nanoTime();
}

}
```

Ok, so I need to create a fractal design that will basically create rectangles at all four corners of a initial rectangle, and then at each open corner of the subsequent rectangles, shown in this picture.

[image]

So the problem I am running into is with the top right rectangles (method TR).
They are not spaced correctly, but according to my math, they should be.

Another question I would have is how would I create the three rectangles from each rectangle without any overlapping.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use ints but rather doubles. Then cast to int when doing the actual drawing.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly, but I still cant seem to get the other rectangles to make it a true fractal, is it possible to make another recursive call on each of the main directions to put those rectangles in?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work, thank you again

Comment: Consider posting an answer to your own question, or removing it, if it has no benefit for future readers.